# Binomial Coefficient in C program explanation

Tags: c, binomial-coefficients

So I have to write a program that prints out the eleven 10th order binomial coefficients. I came across this code that does what I needed, but I'm trying to understand why it works.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int binomialCoeff(int n, int k)
{
    if(k == 0)return 1;
    if(n <= k) return 0;

    return (n*binomialCoeff(n-1,k-1))/k;
}

int main()
{
    int k;
    for(k=10;k>=0;k-=1)
    {
          printf("%d\n", binomialCoeff(10, k));
    }
```

I get why the int main part works, I just don't get how the binomialCoeff calculation is made. I'm relatively new to all of this coding stuff, so thank you for the help!

Comment: What don't you understand: the mathematical formula, recursion, or C syntax?

Comment: I don't understand how (n*binomialCoeff(n-1,k-1))/k equates to the formula n!/((n-k)!k!)

Comment: The former uses recursion. Derive the recursive version of the latter formula and I think you'll see the connection.

Comment: @Nick Write out the formula for a binomial coefficient with n-1 and k-1, and then see what happens when you multiply it by n and divide by k. Is it different from the formula for a binomial coefficient with n and k?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call?

Comment: I believe there is an error in the original code: `if(n <= k) return 0;`. The case `n == k` should return 1, not 0, as there is a single combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually pretty elegant.

The function `binomialCoeff` is a recursive function with 2 base conditions. If `k == 0`, you return just `1`. If `n<k` you return 0. So if none of that is true, you recall the same function by subtracting one from `n` and `k`.  This repeats resulting in

n * (binomialCoeff(n-1,k-1))/k

So say N is 10 and K is 7

you get

```
 10*(binomialCoeff(9,6)/7)
```

Just to keep things simple, lets call the first time `binomialCoeff` is called res1. Which simplifies things to:

```
10*(res1/6)
```

but `res1` itself calls `binomialCoeff`

resulting in

```
 9*(binomialCoeff(8,5)/6)
```

which we can call `res2`

so we get

```
10*(res2/6)
```

and so on until you meet the base conditions; resulting in a series of `n`'s multiplied together.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I understand it now!